# Creating an annotation of my own to extend JUnit4 behaviour

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I've been looking for resources on how to extend JUnit4 with my own annotations.

I'd like to be able to define a `@ExpectedProblem` with which I could label some of my tests. I've seen there seems to be some material on the net on how to extend TestNG, but I could fine none to extend JUnit4.

Has anyone here extended JUnit4 in the past?

Thanks

Comment: If by @ ExpectedProblem, you mean you're expecting the test to fail, you may be interested in a JUnit @ Rule, available at: https://github.com/ttsui/pending (Disclaimer: that was written by a colleague of mine).

Comment: Thanks, but it is not related in any way to pending tests nor expecting the test to fail. What I need is something similar, indeed, to @Test(expecting = Exception), but only a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want your `@ExpectedProblem` annotation to do, another option is to create a `@Rule`.

This requires JUnit 4.7+, but should be simpler than implementing your own `Runner`.

For instance, if you want an annotation to say, "this test should throw an exception" then you'll want to take a look at the [`@ExpectedException`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) rule. Even if that's not enough for your needs it can provide a good starting point for implementing your own rule.

Comment: Rules seemed like a nice idea at first until I saw that "The advantage of this approach over Rules is that Rules are always class scoped" @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099633/does-testng-support-something-like-junit4s-rule/6100111#6100111. I need them to be method scoped (I may want to have 1 method with my annotation and another one without it!).

Comment: @devoured elysium Within your method rule, you can check for the presence of any particular annotation on the method, and have the Rule act as a noop if the annotation is missing.

Comment: +1 on Grundlefleck's comment

@devoured elysium That's exactly what I'd do—check the target of the `MethodRule` upon invocation for the annotation we're interested in, and modify the test execution based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Basic approach is to create your own class runner. For instance, by extending the [`org.junit.runners.ParentRunner`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.html) or [`org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html) classes. You would then annotate your test class with `@RunWith(<your class runner>.class)`. In your runner, you could then analyze the test-class to check for annotations and take appropriate actions etc. Found this googling: http://tedyoung.me/2011/01/23/junit-runtime-tests-custom-runners/

This is how Spring modeled their JUnit support, using the [`org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm just going to ask you the obvious: isn't there a way to avoid having to pollute all my test methods with that clumsy @RunWith()?

Comment: No, AFAIK there is no way to configure a runner globally. Worth noting though is that JUnit itself recommends always using the @RunWith annotation on all your test-classes to ensure future proofing. If your test-class is a JUnit 4 test, it should be annotated @RunWith(JUnit4.class). The current release (JUnit 4) defaults to a BlockJUnit4ClassRunner unless otherwise specified.